# How to catch username or password using hook_form_alter

Tags: forms, 8

I need to catch username/password using the `hook_form_alter()`. I'm using this code:

```
function sds_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id ) {

  if (in_array($form_id, ['user_login_block_form', 'user_login_form'])) {  
    $username= $form_state->getValue('name');
    echo "Username Value".$username;
  }

}
```

but it returns `null`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please provide what you want to achieve by catching the username and password so we can provide better solution for your requirement. hook_form_alter is called before form is rendered. So you'll always get the username and password empty, because user has not yet entered that info in form.

Comment: @Yogesh . thanks for the response i want to get the username and password after the form was submitted because i want to query the username and password from other platform specifically in salesforce.
Now according to you , i think im in a wrong track can you help me out of this.. thanks a lot.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use in VALIDATE function like

```
$form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_user_validate';
```

In this you can all values even if there is no successful values in it.
But remember to call your function first before default validate function.

Answer (score 1):

When `hook_form_alter()` is invoked, the form has not been submitted yet, so you cannot get any value from `$form_state`. You need to add a form submission handler, and from that get the username.

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_user_submit';
```

If you are, instead, trying to get the default value set in the form, then you should use the following code, in your `hook_form_alter()` implementation.

```
$default_name = $form['name']['#default_value'];
```

It would still return an empty value, since Drupal doesn't set a default value for the username, but that is the correct code to get the default value of a form element from `hook_form_alter()`.

Comment: hi @kiamlaluno , its good and working but 

$form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_user_submit' bu works only if the form was successful (ie if username and pass is valid or true) but i want to catch the username and password even if it's not a authenticated user!
can we do that though?

Comment: I did these:
 * add $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_user_submit'; in my hook_form_alter.
*in my mymodule_user_submit I get the $form_state->getvalue('name or pass').
these code are working but now the problem it's only triggered and executed when the form was successful , now i'm wodering if i can get those user inputs right before the it was submitted or trigger the function mymodule_upload_enabled_types_submit even though the login is failed .!